# My ArrayList is not getting sorted by Collections.sort()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to sort an Array by Collections.sort because SDK<24 but it's doing nothing, the array is in the same order, this is the code of my Comparator:

```
public class ComparatorFecha implements Comparator<Dinero> {

@Override
public int compare(Dinero o1, Dinero o2) {
    return o1.getFecha().compareTo(o2.getFecha());
}
}
```

Here is the class Dinero:

```
public class Dinero implements Serializable {

private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private int total;
private String date;
private String id;
private Date fecha;

public Dinero(String nombre, String descripcion, int total, String date) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.total = total;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return date;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.date = fecha;
}


public Date stringToDate(String d1){
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "FECHA CAMBIADA");
        Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(d1);
        return date1;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "FECHA NO CAMBIADA");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And finally here is which is supposed to sort:

```
     public void getIngresos(String user, IngresosIsLoaded iLoaded){
    final  ArrayList<Dinero> beneficio = new ArrayList<>();
    final IngresosIsLoaded ingresosIsLoaded = iLoaded;
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(user).child("Ingresos");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            beneficio.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String nombreAux = ds.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                String descAux = ds.child("descripcion").getValue().toString();
                String fecha = ds.child("fecha").getValue().toString();
                int precioAux = Integer.parseInt(ds.child("total").getValue().toString());
 dinero.setFecha(dinero.stringToDate(fecha));
                dinero.setId(ds.getKey());
                gastos.add(dinero);
            }
            Collections.sort(gastos, new ComparatorFecha());
            gastosLoaded.gastosIsLoaded(gastos);
```

My array is not getting sorting, dont know why, also, there is no log of the class stringToDate, like is not making the function, maybe this could be the problem if "fecha" doesnt exists, nothing will be sorted.

Thanks!

Comment: can you try changing to `o2.getFecha().compareTo(o1.getFecha())` ? Off course this is not the main issue, but just want to make sure that whether comparator is being called or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. As in: please include example code that shows *real* data, and how you sort them, and what comes out of the sort. From what you are showing here, things should be working, there is no obvious bug methinks.

Comment: what is your criteria for sorting items ? by date or by name or something else ?

Comment: Can you show the code that's calling `Dinero.setFecha()`? Is it setting the same date on all instances? (And since null values are allowed, consider whether your comparator should test for null values ...)

Comment: Did you debug before and after the call to Collections.sort to check the values of Fecha ? Maybe they’re all the same ? Or maybe you can show how you’re adding values to gastos fully.

Comment: I've uploaded the full code for Dinero.setFecha, and my criteria of sorting is by date.

Comment: Hello, you're sorting gastos list but is it the displayed list? I can't see where gastos is created bu i clearly see that your clear beneficio. Aren't your sorting a list that you're not displaiing?

Answer (score 0):

Since your fecha field is not initialized in constructor, it will be null until you call setFecha().  To deal with null values in the sort, change your sort line as follows:

```
Collections.sort(gastos, Comparator.nullsFirst(new ComparatorFecha()));
```

Comment: Good idea -- but if the values were null in the OP's case, he would have got an exception in his Comparator code above.

Comment: @AndyThomas if the o1 parameter to his comparator is non-null, the Date compareTo() may be properly handling a null o2 parameter thus no exception

Comment: @Palamino given this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date) the result would be nullPointerException

Comment: @Nemesis but we don't know if he is using java.util.Date because he did not specify the import or package of the Date class in his code snippet

Comment: It sounds like you're presuming that the date type is neither a `java.util.Date` nor its subclass `java.sql.Date`, that some dates are null and some aren't -- and that the sorting algorithm always picks the non-null values for the first argument in the constructor, and never compares two null values.

Comment: @AndyThomas I not presuming anything.  I offered a solution that improves his code, period.  Why not offer a solution of your own rather than busting my $@#$?

Comment: It's a good suggestion. It would be a great comment. But it does not answer the OP's question.